# How to detect vertical and horizontal lines ?

Tags: image, opencv, process

How to detect vertical and horizontal lines ? i know  opencv provide the function based on hough transform to detect all direction lines,but it`s low_performance to compute all direction lines because i just want to dectect Ver and Hon lines .Any suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Are the lines in perfect vertical or horizontal directions? (0 degree or 90 degree?)

Comment: You can modify OpenCV's HoughTransform code so that every point on the edge only votes to limited degrees (e.g. 0 +- 5 and 90 +- 5), this way you should get 180/20 = 9X speed-up. Given you need smaller memory to hold Hough space, the actually speed-up would be bigger than 9X.

Answer (score 3):

[HoughLinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp) is the easiest approach. You can filter out the angles that aren't horizontal or vertical.

However, if you want to use a potentially faster approach that only detects certain angles, you can try cv::Sobel. There's some sample code here that detects vertical and horizontal edges:

http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/CoffeeWatcher/trunk/ImageUtils.cpp

Comment: jspal, the code show the how to get edge but not get edge line.